# react apollo graphql and google authentication flow

Tags: express, authentication, graphql, react-apollo, google-authentication

I am trying to make a complete flow authentication with google on a react apollo graphql based app. I use [react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) for the frontend part and graphql / express with [google-auth-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library) for the backend part.
My current authentication flow is:

- Get google token id with react-google login from frontend.
- Call googleLogin mutation of my graphql server with tokenId
  parameter.
- On backend use verifyIdToken function of react-auth-library and get
  payload of user and create or get user who match with email of
  payload.
- Send user info and current tokenId on frontend.
- On frontend, store the response of my backend in context to
  instantiate the user session and use it to manage routing of my react
  app.

My authorization flow is pretty much the same: Backend side in graphql context, check token Id from authorization header, use verifyIdToken of `google-auth-library` to get user payload and return the found user. In each protected mutation, check if the graphql context has a user field.

With this flow, I encountered several problems and I have no solution to fix that properly. My first issue is when a user is connected for a long time my tokenId stored in the authorization header becomes deprecated. I have no idea how to refresh user connection. My only actual solution is to redirect the user to the login page when the server throws an authentication error, and basically use the automatic sign in of react-google-login to launch the authentication process again.
I'm worried that my authentication / authorization flow is not good. If anyone has any advice or remarks regarding my flow please let me know. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

As for how to refresh user token/connection you should be able to use refreshTokenSetup function, from Google res, it will take care of handling new tokenIds for you in easy way

I found a very useful article here:
https://dev.to/sivaneshs/add-google-login-to-your-react-apps-in-10-mins-4del

Here is another good one:

https://www.apollographql.com/blog/setting-up-authentication-and-authorization-with-apollo-federation/